# Finite group theory - validity of the following conjecture

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, contest-math, cyclic-groups

Wonder whether the following conjecture holds:

*Let: $(G,*)$ - finite group, in which every proper subgroup is cyclic. Then: $(G,*)$ is cyclic.*

Intuitively, there are no trivial counterexamples. However, I may miss something. Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't even have to be abelian...$S_3$ is an example.

Comment: $S_3$ has a cyclic subgroup of order 3, and several subgroups of order 2.

Comment: If this was true then it would follow immediately by induction that all finite groups were cyclic.